# Turning Dictionary to String

Tags: python

so I wanna turn a dictionary to str with keys and values of "10: 2, 8: 1, 12: 5" and to have space and comma separate them like "10 2, 8 1, 12 5"

Comment: Hello :) What code have you tried so far to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `list` of strings(adding variables using f string) and then use `join` to join them together

```
my_dict = {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
my_str = ", ".join([f'{k} {v}' for k,v in my_dict.items()])
print(my_str)
```

```
1 2, 2 3, 3 4
```